# Cut a convex polygon with a line to achieve a given area

Tags: area, polygons

Given are:

- The ordered points of a convex, non-intersecting polygon
- An area value (always smaller than the area of the initial polygon)

Question:

- Where does a horizontal line have to cut through the polygon, so one of the two resulting polygons has exactly the given area?

Context:

- This is needed for a feature in a game. Procedurally generated (random) terrain shall be floodable with water bodies of player-controled volume.

What I have tried so far:
Unfortunately not a lot as I'm missing an entry point for an efficient algorithm.

What I could do is to sorta apply the "divide and conquer" method: Slice the polygon into two halves and recompute the area of each half.
If volume of lower half is too small, split the upper half and add its half to the lower half from before. Otherwise split lower half and continue from there.
Repeat this until the area is close enough to the target value.

Unfortunately that results in recomputing area over and over which might be too slow for a real-time feature.

Any more mathematical approach?

Comment: It's fairly quick to calculate the area of a polygon in case you decide to use your "divide and conquer" approach: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula

Comment: What immediately came to mind was: take the user's first point, then find the areas created by splitting the polygon in two by way of a line segment to each vertex. Iterate around cyclically (vertices in order). Once you've tipped from one side being less than the other to the other way around, you know that the halfway point is between those two vertices. Then find the halfway point between those two vertices and recompute and compare to the previous two values. Iterate further. Convexity is key to finding the midpoint and convergence of this algorithm. Use the shoelace formula for areas.